# Validate URL with AngularJS and HTML 5

Tags: html, angularjs, regex, validation

Good morning all:

Looks like a very common question, but after googling for hours I am not able to figure this out: how to validate an URL including `www` without `http`.

These is what I did:

1. Used the input type url: it does not accept `www.google.com`;
2. Changed the input type to `text` and used `ng-pattern`: I still get the `www.google.com` invalid;
3. Changed different regex but still not working.

So when I click on the submit button, I show an alert if the form is invalid (true invalid, false valid). Here is [my Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3RhcF2LdEcvmwymxZ6Hp)

Thanks for the help

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-validation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8234912/3110058 use the pattern in this it is working fine on your pluncker.
pattern is 
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of binding the regex to scope, you could directly add the regex to `ng-pattern` attribute. Like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/" ng-model="website">
```

I have updated the plunkr. Please take a look at this. [Plukr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SkbEVdb1GULnmlqz3dTc?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

The thing here is, if you want to bind `ng-pattern` from controller, your regex shouldn't contain the starting and ending `/`s. Like this:

```
$scope.regex = "^(http[s]?:\\/\\/){0,1}(www\\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\\.]{0,1}$"
```

But, if you directly specify pattern like `ng-pattern="/^(http|https|...)$/"`, you need the extra `/`s as well.

[**working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/eSlBepkXmtn7pYkzNcJZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for that! I apreciate the help with the basic concepts. It still get valid for this URL: fdsfsfsfsf

Comment: @MarcosF8 had forgotten to escape the escape slashes. works now. Updated plunker too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ng2-validation library. It can be used to perform most validations you should ever need. Angular2 custom validation, inspired by jQuery validation.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can also use **[AngularJs builtin URL validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Burl%5D)**.

```
<script>
angular.module('urlExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.url = {
    text: 'http://google.com'
  };
}]);
</script>

<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<label>URL:
  <input type="url" name="input" ng-model="url.text" required>
<label>
<div role="alert">
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
  Required!</span>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.url">
  Not valid url!</span>
</div>
 <tt>text = {{url.text}}</tt><br/>
 <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
 <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
 <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
 <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
<tt>myForm.$error.url = {{!!myForm.$error.url}}</tt><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `

```js
if (this.resource.url.match("^(https:\/\/|http:\/\/)")) {
if (this.resource.url.match("^(https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/www\.)?([da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})")) {

           
         }

         else
         {
          errorMessages.push("url is invalid");

         }

      }
      else {
         errorMessages.push("url is invalid");

      }
```

`

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation to your solution

Comment: 0

in the above if condition it's validate the http: and https: if url matches it goes into second if condition where the full url "https://www.google.com" matches if anything miss like .com or www it shows the error message